# I need to know how to retrieve data from database to multiple pages using resource controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

As I am a newbie to Laravel, this is my first Laravel project.

This is my controller.

ProductsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
         $arr['products'] = Product::all();
        return view('admin.products.index')->with($arr);

       $productsAll = Product::get();
       return view ('index')->with(compact('productsAll'));
      
      
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, Product $product, Category $category)
    {

        if($request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName())
        {
            $ext =$request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
            $request->prod_image_path->storeAs('public/admin',$file);
        }else{
            $file ='';
        }

        $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        $product-> prod_meta_title = $request-> prod_meta_title;
        $product-> prod_description = $request-> prod_description;
        $product-> prod_category = $request-> prod_category;
        $product-> prod_price = $request-> prod_price;
        $product-> prod_discount = $request-> prod_discount;
        $product-> prod_image_path = $file;
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
       
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        $arr['product'] = $product;
        return view('admin.products.edit')->with($arr);

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        if($request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName())
        {
            $ext =$request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
            $request->prod_image_path->storeAs('public/admin',$file);
        }else{
            $file ='';
        }
        $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        $product-> prod_meta_title = $request-> prod_meta_title;
        $product-> prod_description = $request-> prod_description;
        $product-> prod_category = $request-> prod_category;
        $product-> prod_price = $request-> prod_price;
        $product-> prod_discount = $request-> prod_discount;
        $product-> prod_image_path = $file;
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
       Product:: destroy($id);
       return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }
}
```

To view in admin.products page, I used this below code.

```
  public function index()
        {
          
         $arr['products'] = Product::all();
        return view('admin.products.index')->with($arr);
        }
```

To view in the index page, I used this below code.

```
public function index()
        {
       $productsAll = Product::get();
        return view ('index')->with(compact('productsAll'));
        }
```

how can I use both functions in index function. Or what is the good practice to solve this problem?

And this is my index page.

index.blade.php

```
 @foreach($productsAll as $p)    
                                    <a href="../shop/product-categories-7-column-full-width.html" class="d-block py-2 text-center">
                                            <img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="{{ asset('assets/img/300X300/img6.jpg')}}" alt="Image Description">
                                            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p -> prod_name }}</h6>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    @endforeach
```

Comment: You have 2 `index` function on same controller? On your first code, you define two `return`,  then 2nd return wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two possible ways to do it:

1. Extend your current controller with an additional method (e.g. `indexAdmin`)

```
    public function index()
    {
       $productsAll = Product::get();
       return view ('index')->with(compact('productsAll'));
    }

    public function indexAdmkn()
    {
        $arr['products'] = Product::all();
        return view('admin.products.index')->with($arr);
    }
```

1. Adhere to the [resource controller principle](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers) and create a separate controller for your admin (e.g. `ProductsAdminController`)

By the way, if you're new to Laravel, I can highly recomment Laracasts. They have free training videos available as well. E.g. [this one](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/21) on controllers.

Comment: Same as what? The method name is just a name, though show and index adhere to a standard convention.

Comment: Actually my requirement is, my e-commerce page should be load from database. Eg product name, category,  images....etc.of few products. How can I go for it?

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-models . You can put this code in your Controller and use a View to display it.